# Is Scene2d the best approach for creating a tetris like game using libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I would like to know if using Scene2d is the best approach for creating a tetris like game using libgdx ?

If yes, what's the approach ? each block is an actor ?

How can I achieve this easily ?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a bit of a broad question for this kind of format isn't it? :-) I'll try and answer anyway - to get your tetris game going (without much knowledge of libgdx), just take apart & understand an existing example! Download https://github.com/jmillikan/gdx-tetris and have a play around with it, you'll figure out the best fitting approach to execute your specific idea soon enough. Happy coding :-).

Answer (score 0):

For simple games, like Tetris, you don't need to use something as complicated as Scene2d. Instead, just use a 2 dimensional array that represents the board.

```
board[x][y]=0  //Empty
board[x2][y2]=1  //Filled (or give each block an id)
```

The draw your screen with a spritebatch.